# Ajax request for server side data for each page in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, server-side

I am using Jquery Datatables to load an array of array of data (aaData) obtained via ajax call from server side. I don't want to pull whole of the data at once rather I need to make ajax request for loading data every time user clicks "prev" or "next" in Datatables pagination.

How can this be achieved ?I want to make an ajax call and fetch results on the fly for that page only.

Below is the javascript code where in I am making a call.

```
$.ajax({              
 type: "GET",
 url: "ajaxBacklog",
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data: null,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(json){                  
     oTable = $("#backlogTable").dataTable({
         "aaData": json.aaData,
         "bProcessing": true,
         "bServerSide": true,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "bJQueryUI": true,
         "bRetrieve": true,
         "bPaginate": true,
         "bStateSave": true,
         "bSort": true,
         "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
         "iDisplayLength": 25,
         "oLanguage": {
                 "sProcessing": "<img src='resources/images/loader.gif'/>",
                 "sEmptyTable": "No records found."
             },
         "aoColumns": [
             { "sClass": "alignCenter"},
             { "sClass": "left"},
             { "sClass": "left"},
             { "sClass": "left"},
             { "sType": 'date-uk', "sClass":"datecolumn"},
             { "sType": 'date-uk', "sClass":"datecolumn"},
             { "sClass": "left"},
             { "sClass": "left"}
         ],
         "error": function() {
             alert("Failed to load Data");
         }
     });
    }
   }
);
```

I have also followed the [server side processing](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) of datatables as well but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

In datatables server-side processing every click on 'prev'/'next' button (also filter, sorting etc) call request (out of the box) to function specified in [sAjaxSource](http://datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource) property - you can check this call in your browser console.

Call have lot of usefull parameters. You need to use `iDisplayLength` and `iDisplayStart` in your function for cut (after sort and filter) your set of data from `iDisplayStart` to `iDisplayStart+iDisplayLength`.

You should of course change your code structure as you can see in [datatables documentation](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) - define datatables initialization code and indicate ajax source in `sAjaxSource` property.

Comment: I have an array list of array list of String (basically my aaData) which i populate after fetching data from DB and looping through it and once my aaData gets populated, its displayed in the table. How can i modify my code to make the things work?
'for (BacklogVO obj : backlogVO) {
ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
row.add(addActionColumn());
row.add(obj.getTask());
row.add(obj.getTaskType());                     row.add(obj.getOwnedBy());
row.add(obj.getStatus());                        row.add(obj.getPriority());
aaData.add(row);
}'

Comment: here is example for json format: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: server response which i get is this
`{
   "aaData":[
        [
  "<img src="actionImage.png">,
  "AB MIDT DATA PROCESSING",
  "Pre-sales",
  "Kuldeep Singh",
  "11-04-2013",
  "17-04-2013",
  "WIP",
  "High"
  ]
 ]
}`
But still I am not able to fit it to my need. What i know about datatables is, its brings whole of the data and store it in browser's memory and since it has whole of the data, pagination, sorting  and filtering performance is very quick. I need an ajax call on every pagination number click, telling server to bring let say 25 records each time. How can this be achieved?

Comment: As I mention in answer in every call you should return from server only part of your data, for example - only 25 records

Comment: thats what I am asking  how to make that call on each request ? As u can see in the code above, the URL points to a method in struts action where aaData is populated

Comment: when you define datatables and point URL in sAjaxSource, call on each request will be working out of the box

Comment: sAjaxSource doesn't seems to work as it is not fetching the data as i am not able to give clear URL.
I am doing this in JS code
`"sAjaxSource" : json.aaData` 
 but its not able to render the response.
The URl **ajaxBacklog** is mapped in struts.xml to a method which is populating aaData.
`for (BacklogVO obj : backlogVO) { ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>(); row.add(addActionColumn()); row.add(obj.getTask()); row.add(obj.getTaskType()); row.add(obj.getOwnedBy()); row.add(obj.getStatus()); row.add(obj.getPriority()); aaData.add(row); }`
How can i make changes as per requirement?

Comment: Yes i did. But that gave weird results like 
It is fetching all records and displaying them all irrespective of my **iDisplayLength** which is set to 25. Ideally it should show 25 result in first page and so on. Also, at the bottom of the table the text says "Showing 1 to NaN of total NaN entries". I don't know what it is
`oTable = $("#id").dataTable({
"sAjaxSource":"ajaxBacklog",
"bProcessing":true,
"bServerSide":true,
"sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
"bJQueryUI":true,
"bRetrieve":true,
"bPaginate":true,
"bStateSave":true,
"bSort":true,
"aaSorting":[[4,"desc"]],
"iDisplayLength":25,
}
});`

Comment: And this is my table structure

`<table id="backlogTable">

<thead>

<tr>

<th>Actions</th>

<th>Task</th>

<th>Task Type</th>

<th>Owned By</th>

<th>Created Date</th>

<th>Expected End Date</th>

<th>Status</th>

<th>Priority</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

</tbody>

</table>`

Assume that i have these many columns.

Comment: The question is: did your function return all of records? NaN is show because you probably didn't send `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` parameters from your function

Comment: Now, this is what I am doing
My server response is `{ "aaData":[ [ "<img src="actionImage.png">, "AB MIDT DATA PROCESSING", "Pre-sales", "Kuldeep Singh", "11-04-2013", "17-04-2013", "WIP", "High" ] ], "iTotalDisplayRecords":"25","iTotalRecords":"25"}`

Total records getting displayed in the page are 146 rows.

Total records in database is same 146 rows.

Query to fetch the data is normal "select *" query which brings whole data.

Below the data tables, a line says **displaying 1 to 25 records from total 25 records**. 

I am badly stuck now. :(

Comment: but you should query only 25 row in every call, and put this 25 row into aaData list