# Is it possible to set pagination numbers with the total record returned by the server and number of records selected by the user in Jquery DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am new to DataTable.js jquery plugin and trying to put my best effort to explain the stuff I want to know.

As of my requirement, I have to fetch only 10 records by default at a time when I do an ajax request even it match 100 records with the search criteria. 
But the no. of records will change based on the user selection. ie. it may be 5 or 10 or 25 and so on which is available in the show records per page dropdown control.

Ex.
Consider I have 50 records that matches my search criteria and I selected 10 records to show per page. So the first ajax request provide only 10 records and it will be displayed in the table. At the same time I have to show the pagination as 1 2 3 4 5 buttons.

I want to know how to set the pagination like above using total no. of records and no. records shown per page?

Is there any way to do this?

Any help will appreciate!.

Comment: use [pageLength](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) and [lengthMenu](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) to specify the entries in the length drop down

Comment: Can you please take a look at the Ex. scenario I have given in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Data table basically works on html table and create pagination on table data. Datatable does not provide this type of functionality. may be following link help you
[Ajax request for server side data for each page in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945798/ajax-request-for-server-side-data-for-each-page-in-datatables)

Comment: Thanks RK. Your reference link is not valid for my question. I am expecting something more specifically to showing page numbers in pagination area.